# YouTube API - annotations

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Никак не могу найти метод для добавления annotation к видео через youtube API. Это вообще возможно сделать каким-нибудь образом? Или как-то автоматизировать добавление аннотаций к множеству видео?

Comment: Думаю это ответ на вопрос:


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221531/how-can-i-get-annotation-data-from-yt-api

Comment: @sanu0074 спасибо, да так и есть